# mongodb lookup bad performance

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following data:
collection1:
{ _id:“ff273fc0-b19a-4ed4-8b84-16971a39a672”, V1:“c1_0” }
…
collection2:
{_id: “d2598fbf-3772-4f11-b353-32e0eebb3ef3”, Id2:“ff273fc0-b19a-4ed4-8b84-16971a39a672”, V1:“c2_0”}
…
collection4:
{_id: “0af96153-0871-49e5-9f0d-cb22c4f2f5f8”, Id4: “d2598fbf-3772-4f11-b353-32e0eebb3ef3”, V1: “c4_0”}
…

I have indexes on collection2.Id2 and collection4.Id4.
I have approximately 1 million records in collection1, 3 million in collection2 and 10 million in collection4.

On collection 1 I do a pipeline aggregate:

```
{ "$lookup", {
            { "from", "collection2"},
            {"localField", "_id"},
            {"foreignField", "Id2"},
            {"as", "c2"}
         }
},
{ "$unwind", {
            { "path", "$c2"}, { "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays", true }
         }
},
{ "$lookup", {
            { "from", "collection4"},
            {"localField", "c2._id"},
            {"foreignField", "Id4"},
            {"as", "c2.c4"}
         }
},
{ "$unwind", {
            { "path", "$c2.c4"}, { "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays", true }
         }
},
{ "$count", "c" }
```

When I run this pipeline (from .net code but this doesn’t matter), it doesn’t finish in 5 minutes, I didn’t wait for it to see how much it would take.

I know you usually filter the data and do lookup on much fewer records.
But keeping the high level logic without filtering, can I improve the performance of this MongoDB aggregate ?

The exact same setup with indexes and with inner join between the 3 tables in PostgreSQL works in roughly 30 seconds.

I do the $unwinds because its the only way I can obtain a “join” between 3 tables c1 - one to many - c2 - one to many - c4.
I am using MongoDB 6 Community.

Comment: This looks like a very relational schema.  If you are going to use this with MongoDB you may want to redesign to take advantage of the platform's strengths.

Comment: You mean I need to do object inside object ?

Comment: I can't possibly make recommendations like that without understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't have a use case. I am trying to do a benchmark to measure mongodb performance when having to do "joins". Can I improve the query above ?

Comment: Does it perform the same if you return the documents instead of counting?